# Checking for values in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have dataframes in the form of:

```
            price       percentage
Date        
2021-10-11  298.075989  NaN
2021-10-18  308.570007  0.035206
2021-10-25  308.130005  -0.001426
```

I would like to check whether all the percentages (except NaN) are above 2 percent and then I would like to print a certain statement. How do I do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe something like `print('All Above 2%' if df['percentage'].dropna().gt(0.02).all() else 'Not All Above 2%')`

Comment: did it answer your question? If so, please accept or comment otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems a bit off, but does this satisfy your needs?

```
if all(df.percentage.dropna() > 2):
    print('All are above 2 percent!')
```